# Find the lon/lat from a Google Maps link

Tags: google-maps

Does anybody know how (or if it's possible) to get Long/Lat coordinates out of a Google Maps link? Lets say someone has planned a route on the site and sent me this [link](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=Manor+Rd%2FA237&daddr=Redford+Ave+to%3aMollison+Dr+to%3aGreat+Woodcote+Park+to%3aPeaks+Hill&geocode=FcbMDwMd2Kf9_w%3BFXmcDwMdvAT-_w%3BFaSUDwMdFuf9_w%3BFZR8DwMdBP39_w%3BFbZ4DwMdnhP-_w&hl=en&mra=dme&mrcr=3&mrsp=4&sz=15&dirflg=w&sll=51.348815,-0.139604&sspn=0.021872,0.038581&ie=UTF8&ll=51.346376,-0.124111&spn=0.087493,0.154324&z=13).

If I decode the URL I can see there are 5 markers on the route; 'geocode=FcbMDwMd2Kf9_w;FXmcDwMdvAT-_w;FaSUDwMdFuf9_w;FZR8DwMdBP39_w;FbZ4DwMdnhP-_w' but how would I convert those to long/lat coords?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It seems that the geocode parameter is actually the start/end points of each polyline and not the the lng/lat of the markers. I found a decoder which outputs the coords of the lines. http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/googlemaps/encodepolyline/decode.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exact enough, but it might be worth a try. The link you provided has two interesting parameters, namely `saddr` and `daddr`.

```
saddr=Manor+Rd%2FA237
daddr=Redford+Ave+to%3aMollison+Dr+to%3aGreat+Woodcote+Park+to%3aPeaks+Hill
```

Where `saddr` obviously is the starting point, and `daddr` seems to encode all waypoints and of course the destination. Now I think you could feed this to the [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/).

Sample request to the API (with [waypoints](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints)):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Manor%20Rd&destination=Peaks%20Hill&waypoints=Redford%20Ave|Mollison%20Dr|&sensor=false

I had to leave out "Great Woodcote Park" as waypoint, it didn't find any directions than, but I leave that task to US citizens (maybe that location is ambiguos). :)